# How to remove measurements and associated values that are lower than a threshold in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with Gest variables associated with a Sys and a Dia variable. I would like to remove the Gest variables and the associated Sys/Dia if the Gest value is less than or equal to that of another variable (GA).

This is an example of my data: (My actual data has over 60 Gest variables)

```
ID <- c(1,2)
Gest1 <- c(150, 165)
Sys1 <- c(140, 110)
Dia1 <- c(90, 75)
Gest2 <- c(160, 170)
Sys2 <- c(130, 120)
Dia2 <- c(80, 80)
Gest3 <- c(172, 180)
Sys3 <- c(120, 129)
Dia3 <- c(90, 86)
GA <- c(165, 167)

DF1 <- data.frame(ID, Gest1, Sys1, Dia1, Gest2, Sys2, Dia2, Gest3, Sys3, Dia3, GA)
```

[image: DF1]

This is what I would like the data to look like:

[image: DF2]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You mean higher or equal, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a couple of pivots.  First, the `pivot_longer()` puts the measure in the rows allowing you to isolate measures of `Gest` that fall above a certain level and setting all variables in the row to NA if that's the case.  The `pivot_wider()` moves back to the original wide form:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ID <- c(1,2)
Gest1 <- c(150, 165)
Sys1 <- c(140, 110)
Dia1 <- c(90, 75)
Gest2 <- c(160, 170)
Sys2 <- c(130, 120)
Dia2 <- c(80, 80)
Gest3 <- c(172, 180)
Sys3 <- c(120, 129)
Dia3 <- c(90, 86)
GA <- c(165, 167)

DF1 <- data.frame(ID, Gest1, Sys1, Dia1, Gest2, Sys2, Dia2, Gest3, Sys3, Dia3, GA)

DF1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(Gest1:Dia3, names_pattern="(.*)(\\d$)", names_to=c(".value", "measure")) %>% 
  mutate(across(Gest:Dia, ~case_when(Gest >= GA ~ NA_real_, 
                                     TRUE ~ .x))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="measure", values_from=c("Gest", "Sys", "Dia")) %>% 
  select(ID, ends_with("1"), ends_with("2"), ends_with("3"), GA)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#>      ID Gest_1 Sys_1 Dia_1 Gest_2 Sys_2 Dia_2 Gest_3 Sys_3 Dia_3    GA
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    150   140    90    160   130    80     NA    NA    NA   165
#> 2     2    165   110    75     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA   167
```

---

Here's a streamlined version thanks to @Mael

```r
DF1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(Gest1:Dia3, names_pattern="(.*)(\\d$)", names_to=c(".value", "measure")) %>% 
  mutate(across(Gest:Dia, ~ replace(.x, Gest > GA, NA))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="measure", values_from=c("Gest", "Sys", "Dia"), names_vary="slowest")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#>      ID    GA Gest_1 Sys_1 Dia_1 Gest_2 Sys_2 Dia_2 Gest_3 Sys_3 Dia_3
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1   165    150   140    90    160   130    80     NA    NA    NA
#> 2     2   167    165   110    75     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer, not that you can use `names_sep = ""` and `names_vary = "slowest"` as well.

Comment: and `~ replace(.x, Gest > GA, NA))` instead of `case_when`, but that's up to tastes

Comment: You should post your answer.  It seems like it is different enough from mine.  I'll up vote it.

Comment: It has the same logic (double pivoting with across inside), so not really different.

Answer (score 3):

Base R shenanigans

```
tmp=data.frame(DF1[,grepl("Gest",colnames(DF1))]<=DF1$GA)
tmp[!tmp]=NA

do.call(
  cbind,
  sapply(
    colnames(DF1),
    function(x){
      y=gsub("\\D","",x)
      ifelse(
        y!="",
        DF1[x]*tmp[gsub("\\D","",colnames(tmp))==y],
        DF1[x]
      )
    }
  )
)

     ID Gest1 Sys1 Dia1 Gest2 Sys2 Dia2 Gest3 Sys3 Dia3  GA
[1,]  1   150  140   90   160  130   80    NA   NA   NA 165
[2,]  2   165  110   75    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA 167
```